# Overlaying two grids

Tags: matlab, grid

I would like to ask some advice about the best way to approach this problem:

I have drawn two grids; one square, one hexagonal.

I am overlaying the hexagonal grid over the square one.

[image]

What would be best to average the squares underlying each hexagon so each hexagon's value is the average of the squares underneath?

What do you think would be the most efficient way to do this? Is there an inbuilt command which I cannot find?

Comment: Do you have the Mapping toolbox? If so, have you seen the [`polyxpoly`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) function?

Comment: Sure do, do you think I should find all the intersection points and mesh the grid together as new shapes? Or polybool?

Comment: It depends... If you want to actually find the intersection areas, then probably `polybool`, but if you just want to know with which squares it intersects then you probably don't need all that extra complexity.

Comment: cheers for your replies. Hm, if each square is assigned a value, and I want the hexagon to be an average of all the squares that overlap into its space, is polybool the only way? Shame there isn't an overlay grid command :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses `polyxpoly` to find the intersection points of a hexagon with a square grid, and then uses `inpolygon` to find out which squares were intersected.

```
% Generate grid of squares
sqSize = 5; 
sqN = 4; 
sqPolyX = [0 0 sqSize sqSize 0]'; 
sqPolyY = [0 sqSize sqSize 0 0]';
offs = (0:sqN-1) * sqSize;
[sqXOff, sqYOff] = meshgrid(offs, offs);

sqX = bsxfun(@plus, sqPolyX, sqXOff(:)');
sqY = bsxfun(@plus, sqPolyY, sqYOff(:)');

% Generate one hexagon
Nsides = 6;
hexTh = (0:Nsides)' * 2*pi / Nsides;
hexSize = 2.5; % "radius"
hexOff = rand(2, 1) * (sqN * sqSize);
hexPolyX = hexSize * cos(hexTh) + hexOff(1);
hexPolyY = hexSize * sin(hexTh) + hexOff(2);

% Find intersections between polygons
[xi, yi] = polyxpoly([sqX; NaN(1, sqN^2)], [sqY; NaN(1, sqN^2)], hexPolyX, hexPolyY);

% Find squares corresponding to intersections
hexInPolys = false(sqN^2, 1);
for nSquare = 1:sqN^2
    hexInPolys(nSquare) = any(inpolygon(xi, yi, sqX(:, nSquare), sqY(:, nSquare))); 
end
hexInPolys = find(hexInPolys);

% Make some pretty plots
close all;
hold on;
patch(sqX, sqY, rand(size(sqX)));

for nFound = 1:length(hexInPolys)
    fill(sqX(:, hexInPolys(nFound)), sqY(:, hexInPolys(nFound)), 'r')
end

patch(hexPolyX, hexPolyY, rand(size(hexPolyX)))
plot(xi, yi, 'o');
```

Note the additional `NaN`s that must be passed to `polyxpoly` for each polygon to denote the end of one polygon and the start of the next. This is not the case with the non-Mapping-toolbox polygon functions like `inpolygon` and `patch`.

You can't use `inpolygon` directly for this, because it will fail if the polygons intersect but none of the vertices of one are inside the other.

Unfortunately this only works for one hexagon at a time... there's probably a more efficient solution there somewhere, but this is fairly complex without trying to "vectorise" it, so I suggest you start here and optimise only if you run into performance issues.